# Filterable y View.OnClickListener

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy usando un **Filterable** para filtrar datos dentro de un listado y **View.OnClickListener** para seleccionar un campo dentro del listado. Funciona pero cuando lo filtro y selecciono un dato dentro del listado no obtiene lo que filtré sino que selecciona lo que esta en esa posición,

En mi Adapter estoy implementando los dos:

```
 implements Filterable,  View.OnClickListener
```

En mi Activity para seleccionar lo que tengo en el Listado:

```
 customerAdapter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "* " + customerList.get
                                            (recilcerViewCustomer.getChildAdapterPosition( view )).getCardName(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: no me queda muy claro el problema. Te esta devolviendo un customer que puede que ya este filtrado? ese es el problema? puede ser porque estas haciendo el get del customerList y esa lista no esta filtrada? por favor explica un poco más que esta pasando.

Comment: Saludos,
En el listado tengo: 1.Juan, 2.Pedro, 3.Luis . cuando filtro Luis en la pantalla me queda solo luis por el filtro, selecciono luis esperando que el toast me devuelva luis pero en  realidad me devuelve Juan,  y cundo no hago nungun filtro me devuelve lo que selecciono.

Answer (score 0):

Estas recuperando los datos de una lista que no esta filtrada, por eso no te coiniciden los datos.

```
//Asi optienes el indice del item de la lista que fue clickeado, segun el ejemplo index = 0
int index = recilcerViewCustomer.getChildAdapterPosition( view )

//Aqui consigues el nombre del item de la lista. segun el ejemplo cardName = Juan
String cardName = customerList.get(index).getCardName()
```

Entiendo que esperas conseguir Luis y no Juan, esto pasa porque Juan `customerList = [Juan,Pedro,Luis]` y no se modifica cuando se aplica el filtro. Una solucion a este problema seria que tengas una lista con el resultado del filtro `filteredList=[Luis]` entocenes si `filteredList.get(index).getCardName()` te devolvera el resultado correcto.

Tambien podrias agregar el `Customer` como propiedad del `holder` y castearlo en el `onClick` o implementar el `onClick` con un callback que devuelva el `Customer`.

Comment: Me sigue mostrando el dato de la posición de el listado, es decir aun me muestra "Juan" y no "Luis", no se hasta que punto con el recilcerView se puede usar OnClickListener?

Comment: Subi el codigo de tu adapter, asi te puedo ayudar mejor. pense que ese OnClickListener lo habias sobre escrito vos dentro del adapter.

Comment: [SOLUCIÓN]:
 viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "POSICION: "+position +" * " + customerListFilter.get(position).getCardName()  ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

Dentro del Adapter, en onBindViewHolder solo agregué: setOnClickListener